# Excel - what is a workaround for a pivot-style summary of two groups of linked column data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

In Excel, I am building a report with a dashboard that incorporates a map of the country. This map is made up of objects that represent the administrative divisions of the country, and through VBA, the objects change colour according to the presence of projects in that area. The data required for this is pulled from a pivot table of the original data table. The data table is completed by the various project leads and is as simple as possible. This is all working okay.

My issue is that I have two sets of information in the original table that are sets of related binary data, which I do not believe a pivot table can process usefully. A much needed illustration follows:

[image: First example]

In this version I have the project focus as a single text string, and the location as a set of binary fields. This works great. The pivot table counts the projects in each location, and on the dashboard a slicer allows it to be grouped together by default, and then adjusted by project focus. The data in the pivot column it is shown on the map as per the dummy example, with darker shades for higher project counts. This is exactly what I need. However, this isn’t a satisfactory solution, as some projects have multiple focuses, such as Project 3 in this example. When I click the health button on the slicer, project 3 won’t be included. In the full version of this file there are many projects, with many combinations of focuses, so it isn’t practical to have each potential combination listed.

My original data table then should include two sets of binary fields for focus and location, as below. But this seems to be beyond the capability of a pivot table to make sense of.

[image: Second example]

So - I need a way to take this data and produce a single list of locations with project counts against them, as per the first example. This needs to be simply adjustable to specific focus areas (with a slicer or drop down) from the dashboard. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that you're talking about the ability to "Unpivot" data. A cross-tabulated layout like you have doesn’t make for a good PivotTable data source, as you've found out. A crosstab has one of the fields running across the top of the data, and it’s often a Year field, as in the example below:

[image]

Now, a crosstab actually makes it much easier than a flat file for a human to consume data. However, if you make a PivotTable out of a crosstab, you get a very busy PivotTable Fields pane, like the one shown below left, as opposed to the much simpler PivotTable Fields pane on the right:

[image]

Why does this matter? For a couple reasons:

- With the crosstab, you have to drag each of those year fields into
  the VALUES area individually if you want them to show up. On the
  other hand, with the flat file, once you’ve dragged that Revenue
  field to the VALUES area, you decide which years of revenue to show
  (or hide) simply by filtering the Date field.
- With the crosstab, you have to change the number format of all those
  fields in the VALUES area individually. The same goes if you want to
  ditch that “Sum of” prefix or if you want to show the values as
  percentages of the column total; each field needs to be changed
  individually.

So what is the fix? You’ve got to turn that source data from a crosstab into a flat file, a process commonly referred to as unpivoting or normalizing a crosstab.

You need the data to look like this:

[image]

...and not like this:

[image]

If you've just got a small amount of data, you can manually cut and paste to get it into a flat file.

If you've got a version of Excel that has PowerQuery (aka Get and Transform), then there is a native UNPIVOT command that is pretty easy to find videos explaining on YouTube.

If you want a VBA solution, there is heaps of different code out there, including a routine of mine at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/